# How can I split a video into segments of a certain width and height?

Tags: video, video-editing

Say I have a 256x256 video that's 1 minute long, is there a way I can split it into, say, 16 separate 1m long 64x64 videos for each 64x64 segment of the video? Sorry if this is phrased weirdly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ffmpeg` - which is the swiss army knife for video editing - is capable to do this:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -filter:v "crop=64:64:0:0" out1.mp4
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -filter:v "crop=64:64:64:0" out2.mp4
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -filter:v "crop=64:64:128:0" out3.mp4
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -filter:v "crop=64:64:192:0" out4.mp4
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -filter:v "crop=64:64:0:64" out5.mp4
...
```

Comment: Thank you! what's the syntax on the crop argument?

Comment: The crop filter accepts up to 20 arguments. They are described in detail here: https://manpages.debian.org/testing/ffmpeg/ffmpeg-filters.1.en.html

Comment: Thanks :) much appreciated